# Spring MVC ClassNotFoundException on DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm getting the above error while running a sample Spring MVC Web Application. However Index.jsp file is running and after that I'm getting the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Code as follows-

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.yogesh" />  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

Controller.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  
@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  
}
```

---

I have written a simple hellopage.jsp to print the welcome message.

Comment: Make sure you have spring-webmvc-xx.jar in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Where did you put the JAR files?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Luna IDE